# magento custom view.phtml file with all blocks like product type

Tags: magento

I have to create custom view.phtml to file with all the details which are working on product details.

I am able to get most of the details with the help of catalog.xml but having problem in getting product type data in custom view.phtml file.

Like:  PRODUCT_TYPE_simple ,PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable,PRODUCT_TYPE_group means all product type.

I would to call these blocks also in custom .phtml file.

getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
   getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

I have created one controller and one layout file and using my module handler I am calling all required .phtml files using catalog.xml as reference.

Please feel free to connect if more info required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout` open **catalog.xml** if you are using default theme.

replace

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

with your own file

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/yourview.phtml">
```

Comment: Thanks its already did. But product type information is not loading, for example we have created group product so that should also load.

Comment: 1.9.2.1 latest magento

Comment: <!--
Additional block dependant on product type
-->
check for this line and make simillar changes just after that according to product type

Comment: like  `  <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">`
or `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">`

Comment: Sorry in which file: In my layout.xml file?

Comment: in magento 1.9 there are two layout for product one is         `<label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>` and other is for specific one like ` <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">`
have you done on both place

Comment: can you please add your catalog.xml in you question

Comment: why you need a `custom.xml `

Comment: I have to use two view.phtml template to use one different layout and different data.